# Integrated Windows Auth Migration to ADFS 1.0 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, adfs

I am planning to do some migration from Integrated windows auth to ADFS 1.0 for one of my web application in Asp.net/c#, Problem i am having is i cannot completely migrate to this new infrastructure, i need to maintain both system for a while.
question i have is how can i setup my web.configs ? do i use user.configs to override web.configs during promotion to adfs site vs the Windows integrated side. my plan is to host adfs site and Windows integrated site on two different servers.
and how about the development in visual studio how can i handle it?
i am very new to ADFS so i am not very familiar with the ADFS web.config changes.

Comment: If you're starting with AD FS, why would you want to use ADFS 1.0 instead of [tag:adfs2.0]?

Comment: i'm still using .net 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with ADFS 1.0 but if you are planning to use FedUtil (Add STS) and if you are talking about the web.config for the ASP.NET application (i.e. the Relying Party), then simply backup your web.config before you run FedUtil.

Then backup the web.config after you run FedUtil. When you develop or deploy, just ensure you use the relevant web.config.

Comment: i need to support web.config for both integrated windows auth and ADFS, so i have a small issue manating in source control and promotion